# Exposing custom soap service with WSS security in SOAP header

Tags: soap-api, soap

How can we create Salesforce custom web soap service with soap header which will have `wss:Security` elements inside it?

following is the sample custom apex web service

```
global class MyWebService {
    webservice static Id makeContact(String contactLastName, Account a) {
        Contact c = new Contact(lastName = contactLastName, AccountId = a.Id);
        insert c;
        return c.id;
    }
}
```

But how will I define custom soap header elements and ws_security elements?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, you don't have control over the SOAP envelope. Vote for this [idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=087300000006u2wAAA).

As a workaround, you could route your web service calls through an API Gateway or similar middleware  that does support WS-Security and will translate your payload. Mulesoft is a Salesforce product that can do this.

Comment: can we add custom headers for custom Apex soap webservice?

Comment: @sdandamud1 If you're calling a non-Salesforce, 3rd party SOAP webservice from Salesforce, you can add custom headers to your SOAP request in Apex. For SOAP webservices hosted in Salesforce (this question), you can't add headers.

Comment: mine is Apex soap webservice created in sf and converted into wsdl , client needs to use that wsdl and add specific headers then make a request to salesforce. here is my question https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321516/add-custom-headers-for-my-custom-soap-apex-webservice